# Getting Center and Radius of Irregural Object

Tags: c++, mathematics

I have drawn an asteroid object manually , and would like to get its center/radius by a specific equation. I think I can get them by calculated and hard-coded values.

The code to draw the asteroid:

```
float ratio = (float)app::getWindowWidth()/app::getWindowHeight();
gl::pushMatrices();

gl::translate(m_Pos*ratio);

gl::scale(m_size*ratio,m_size*ratio);
gl::color(ci::Color(1,1,1));

    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(20,0),Vec2f(80,0));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(80,0),Vec2f(100,20));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(100,20),Vec2f(100,50));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(100,50),Vec2f(60,100));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(60,100),Vec2f(40,100));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(40,100),Vec2f(50,70));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(50,70),Vec2f(25,90));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(25,90),Vec2f(0,70));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(0,70),Vec2f(20,40));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(20,40),Vec2f(0,20));
    gl::drawLine(Vec2f(0,20),Vec2f(20,0));

gl::popMatrices();

gl::pushMatrices();

float radius = getRadius();

Vec2f center = Vec2f(m_Pos.x+50, m_Pos.y+50);

gl::drawStrokedCircle(center*ratio, 10);
gl::popMatrices();
```

}

According to the answer I have written that code to calculate the radius, is it correct or not ?

```
cinder::Vec2f Asteroid::getCenter()
{
    return ci::Vec2f(m_Pos.x, m_Pos.y);
}

double Asteroid::getRadius()
{
    ci::Vec2f  _vec = (getCenter()- Vec2f(15,5));
    return _vec.length()*0.3f; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the center of the extents, take the max and min of both the x and y values, add them together and divide by two.

In your trivial example:

```
XMin = -15
XMax = 15
YMin = -5
YMax = 5

-15 + 15 = 0, 0/2 = 0
-5 + 5 = = 0, 0/2 = 0
```

So obviously the center is at (0,0)

The radius of the bounding circle is the largest distance from the center to a point that makes up the shape.

Comment: what about the radius of the bounding circle ?

Comment: See my edit, you can check each point or better, check the points that contain one of the maximum x/y values.

Comment: In case of the object is moving, the center will be m_Pos+0 correct ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, it seems getradius is wrong, because it returns a different radius at each frame.. why ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now with `m_Pos`. You can't use a static position (15,5) and a variable center. The (15,5) is an offset from the center, so your radius would be `(getCenter()- (getCenter()+Vec2f(15,5)))` Eventually, you'll want to use variables instead of static values. But this works for proof of concept.

Comment: This is weird equation :),  radius = center - center+offset?

Comment: Can you please explain it mathematically or graphically? I'm really interested to know that :). Thanks

Comment: Yes, I suggest you read through this blog series. The equation seems strange. You're calculating two points, then finding the distance between those two points. The first point is your center and the second point is the farthest extent from your center. http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/

Comment: I have tried your calculations with different shape but it not working correctly, can you tell me whats wrong. I have edited the code.

Comment: You'll have to tell me what's not working about it. I can see you're hard coding a lot of values, so you'd need to have duplicates of these methods for each enemy. You need to implement these calculations programmatically, manually entering in values is not the programmer way.